FragmentContainerview animation ordering with popUpTo and popUpToInclusive
This is the setup in the Main Activity:
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />

I have three fragments (A, B and C). I navigate from A to B and from B to C with a "slide in from right" animation like so:
        <action
            android:id="@+id/a_to_b"
            app:destination="@id/b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />

On Fragment C there is an "X" button that should cancel the flow and go back directly to Fragment A with a slide down animation while popping the back stack:
        <action
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            app:destination="@id/a"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popUpTo="@id/a"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

Everything but the cancel action is working correctly. The problem is that it seems like the ordering on the cancel action is wrong. Fragment A is drawn over Fragment C, so you don`t see the slide out animation. I thought that the exiting Fragment should be drawn over the entering one when there is a pop happening.
Is there any way I can change this behaviour for a specific action?
Here are the animations I am using:
Nothing:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />

Slide in right:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />

Slide out bottom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="300"/>


When you say app:destination="@id/a" in your action, that means you are navigating to a new instance of A (which is, of course, going to be on top of your back stack and thus on top visually). Is that what you actually want to do? An action that pops only would not include that line.

Thanks, @ianhanniballake, you are right! My misunderstanding was that every action needs a destination and that it would just go back to the "popUpTo" target automatically. But when removing the destination and setting "popUpToInclusive" to false it works as expected

The problem was using a destination in the action, which seems to add a new entry instead of just going back. When removing the destination and also setting "popUpToInclusive" to "false" it works as expected:
        <action
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nothing"
            app:popUpTo="@id/a"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />

